# Get call to REST service in Angular results in unknown error

Tags: angular

In my Angular 8 application I try a get call to a rest service which should give back some Json data. My parameter are only link, authorization: basic, username, password. In Postman, the call works correctly and I see the expected data. In my Angular app, I see the message:

> httpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error",

There is my code.

There is my header settings:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type":  "application/json",
    "Authorization": 'Basic ' + btoa("myusername:mypassword")
  })
};
```

There is my service:

```
getMyList() {
  //return this.http.get<any>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', httpOptions).pipe(map(r =>r))
  return this.http.get<any>('mylink', httpOptions ).pipe(map(r =>r))
}
```

There is how I call my service in the component:

```
this.personService.getMyList().subscribe( r => console.log(r))
```

As you can see from a commented row, I also tried to change the real link with a fake json service available in internet for developer's test and in this case all works; and, maybe, it seams that the code is correct. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What does the network tab in the Developer Console show for the HTTP request?

Comment: Is the Angular 8 app and the server app in the same domain? Check the Network tab, high chance that it is a CORS error and you need in your server to allow the Angular 8 domain to connect.

Comment: Both, you are right! In this point of the console I see a CORS error and the backend has another IP addresse of another server. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.techiediaries.com/fix-cors-with-angular-cli-proxy-configuration/?fbclid=IwAR0PvTgToYhQrMXMwIW5JBuOtz8xaEX11WytlRVj-FZul5k5wcKEG4nENpA

This is the solution: proxy configuration. I wrote the IP of the server which host the backend in a specific configuration file and now all works.